# Read .dat files one by one from a folder location, modify them and write to the same file using C# code

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to **C#**. My requirement is to pull 10 `.dat` files from a *shared folder* one by one and *validate them*.

The validation process includes:

1. Look for missing `~` at line 1, 2, and end of the file. Add a `~` if it is missing.
2. Look for extra carriage return at end of file and remove it.
3. Look for extra `~` at line 1, 2, and end of the file. Remove `~` if extra is present.
4. After making above validations. Write back to the same file and save it in the same location.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this is actually not that difficult quite easy actually.. however you need to do some work on your end. First start with writing some code.. then do a google search on how to get a list of all files in a particular dir. location. Then read on how to use the `.Contains` method along with how to read from and write back to a file.. good luck

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I am totally new I did find out how to read a file from a folder location. But not able to loop through all files and modify it.

Comment: For future reference, please make sure to include code snippets to get more accurate and useful answers

Comment: @AP : Here is the code that I have come up with:

Comment: I don't see it @Mish

Answer (score -1):

How to read all the files in a directory and how to iterate over those files: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx

How to create files: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

How to know if a character exists in a line: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

How to replace values in a string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Sorry, but that's the most that I can do to help you without giving away all the code.

Comment: Any sample code that covers my requirement would be really helpful